# Is it possible to specify a label for a field in the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to specify a "label" for a certain field in the model and use it every where in my application.

```
<div class="editor-field">
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.surname) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.surname) %>
</div>
```

To this I'd like to add something like:

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.surname) %>
```

But labelFor already exist and writes out "surname". But I want to specify what it should display, like "Your surname".
I'm sure this is easy =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my project was auto generated I couldn't (shouldn't) alter the designer.cs file.
So I created a meta data class instead, as explained [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1254847.aspx/1?Changing%20the%20display%20name%20of%20a%20field)

```
// Override the designer file and set a display name for each attribute
[MetadataType(typeof(Person_Metadata))]
public partial class Person
{
}

public class Person_Metadata
{
    [DisplayName("Your surname")]
    public object surname { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the `Display` or `DisplayName` attribute on the property in your model.

```
[Display(Name = "Your surname")]
public string surname { get; set; }
```

or

```
[DisplayName("Your surname")]
public string surname { get; set; }
```

Comment: If I add this it says `surname` already exists and I get 29 errors. Where else can I add it? I'm using the same setup as NerdDinner.

Comment: I found it was already declared in the `Test.designer.cs`. Should I add the `[Display(Name = "Your surname")]` here? I thought you weren't suppose to edit the designer file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by adding the DisplayAttribute (from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace) to the property: something like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Your surname")]
public string surname { get; set; }
```

Comment: I found it was already declared in the `Test.designer.cs`. Should I add the `[Display(Name = "Your surname")]` here? I thought you weren't suppose to edit the designer file?